# Will water kept in a beaker get compressed in a lift accelerating upwards?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics

[image: Question from JEE advanced which arose this doubt]

I came across this question while studying fluid mechanics and the answer to the question is that P, Q and R all match to 1 i.e. range does not depend upon gravity, but rather height of water and beaker. But even if that is true, wouldn't the acceleration cause a deformation and reduce the volume, thus reducing the height of the water?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s take scenario 1 - the lift is accelerating vertically upwards with acceleration $a$.

The pressure at the hole in the jar will increase by a factor of

$\displaystyle \frac {g+a} g$

If the liquid obeys [Torricelli’s Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law) then the horizontal velocity of the water jet will increase by a factor

$\displaystyle \sqrt \frac {g+a} g$

which at first leads us to think that $d$ will increase by the same factor.

However, the floor of the lift is accelerating upwards too, which *decreases* the time that each droplet of water is in flight by a factor

$\displaystyle \sqrt \frac g {g+a}$

This effect cancels out the effect of the increased horizontal velocity of the water jet, and the final outcome is that $d$ is unchanged by the acceleration of the lift.

The water in the jar will be compressed very slightly by the acceleration, but the compressibility of water is very, very small (approximately the same order of magnitude as solid rock) so the change in the height of the water will be negligible.

Comment: Would the hypothetical compression of the water not change the "rho" in the pressure equation?

Comment: @ DJohnM Torriceli  says that $v=\sqrt{2gh}$. This is does not depend on $\rho$.